# Angular State provider , state name containing '#' changing to '#/"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a new state for my application, like 
**mydomain.com/#men**. So I did as below:

```js
var categoryNames = ['men','woman']
$stateProvider.state('department', {
        url: '/#{department:' + categoryNames.join('|') +
          '}/',
        views: {
          main: {
            templateUrl: 'category-page.html',
            controller: 'CategoryController as categoryCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
```

When I hit the url **mydomain.com/#men** its changing to **mydomain.com/#/men**.
Is there any way to prevent the **/** from appearing after **#**.

Answer (score 0):

> You should configure [`$locationProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider) and set `html5Mode` to
>   true:

```
angular.module('', []).
   config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
      function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
         $routeProvider. // routes
         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      }
  ]);
```

Comment: switching on the HTML 5 mode will remove the "#" from the state URL. I need the url to be as **mydomain.com/#men**. Is there any way for that?

Comment: it'll delete /#/ and will leave your #men there.